# How to install Emacs 26 on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

To install Emacs on CentOS I use this:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install emacs
```

Nice. But the problem is that... it install old version of Emacs = **24.3**

But I need Emacs 26 to install on CentOS

Is it possible?

Comment: You can always compile yourself! There are many documentation on the internet for any specific version

Comment: @itirazimvar This help me - https://justyn.io/til/compile-emacs-27-on-centos-7/   . Now I has Emacs 27.1 on CentOS 7

Comment: Feel free to answer your question and accept it as correct answer! 
Maybe you have more details to share also :)